# My media queries gets overwritten by normal css code

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

P.S: I'm using React for front-end and SASS for CSS that's why it's 'className' instead of 'class' and there are no brackets in my CSS.

It's not much to explain, basically whenever I try to for example show the burger menu on the table view, it never appears and stays display: none.

```
.logo__area-mobile
    display: none


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
    .logo__area-mobile
        display: block
```

HTML:

```
<header>
  <div className="header-search">
    <div className="logo__area-mobile">
      <button>&#9776;</button>
    </div>
    <div className="header-search-input">
      <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Est: Daredevil, Orange is the new black" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="header-menu">
    <div className="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><NavLink to="/recently" activeClassName="is-active">مضاف مؤخراً</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/series" activeClassName="is-active">المسلسلات</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/movies" activeClassName="is-active">الافلام</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/" activeClassName="is-active" exact>الرئيسية</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div className="logo">
        <Link to="/">EgyMovs</Link>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: What's your HTML?

Comment: Hey @jeanpaulxiao just edited it, you can see the HTML now. :)

Comment: Is that your actual CSS? The media query is missing the brackets in your example.

Comment: ^^ and the html should be "class=" not "className="

Comment: ^^probably using React.

Comment: hey @disinfor sorry for not making this clear already, I'm using SASS for my CSS and React for my front-end so all my classes in HTML are called 'className' :)

Comment: Try to use higher priority of your style. Like adding additional class to your div, or use in selector by tag and class.

Comment: In that case, can you post the compiled output?

Comment: Is your SASS compiling correctly?

Comment: actually, @Fox was right! I checked the compiler and everything worked fine but when I tried to call a higher priority it worked! thanks. :)

Comment: @Laylaz glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use more specific selector for your element.
Like 2 classes or tag name and class name.

Hint for count:

[image]

```
.a .b //00020
#id .a //00110 -- more specific, higher priority
```